# I can access private members in transpiled ES5 code from TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I was studying `TypeScript` myself at [TypeScript's Playground page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html). 
I'm not sure if `TypeScript` transpiles the code well. 
I created a `class` and this class has a `name` as a **private member**. 
So I did some test if I can access to private member of class in transpiled code. 
But, I succeed to access to private member. 
I was just studying `TypeScript`. So I think I chose wrong options maybe.

### Selected Options

(Added) TypeScript Version: `3.5.1` 
Target : `ES5` 
JSX : `None`  
checked options are:

- `noImplicitAny`
- `stricNullChecks`
- `strictFunctionTypes`
- `stricPropertyInitialization`
- `noImplicitThis`
- `noImplicitReturns`
- `alwaysStrict`

---

### My TypeScript code

```js
class Person {
    private _name: string;
    _age: number;

    constructor(name: string, age: number) {
        this._name = name;
        this._age = age;
    }

    setName(name: string) {
        this._name = name;
    }

    getName(): string {
        return this._name;
    }

    setAge(age: number) {
        this._age = age;
    }

    getAge(): number {
        return this._age;
    }
}

const person = new Person('James', 23);
console.log(person.getName()); // James
console.log(person._name);  // error: Property '_name' is private and only accessible within class 'Person'.
console.log(person._age); // 23
```

---

### Transpiled code to `ES 5`

```
"use strict";
var Person = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Person(name, age) {
        this._name = name;
        this._age = age;
    }
    Person.prototype.setName = function (name) {
        this._name = name;
    };
    Person.prototype.getName = function () {
        return this._name;
    };
    Person.prototype.setAge = function (age) {
        this._age = age;
    };
    Person.prototype.getAge = function () {
        return this._age;
    };
    return Person;
}());
var person = new Person('James', 23);
console.log(person.getName());  // James
console.log(person._name); // James
console.log(person._age); // 23
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: @Mu-TsunTsai Thanks for your link. Sorry for that I didn't check duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the moment JavaScript doesn't have truly private members; the notion of `private` in TypeScript is merely there to help you preventing coding mistakes. There is a possibility that in the future, ECMAScript might introduce real private members, but until then, you can still access "private members" after transpiling.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So I need to fix my code as works like private member.